# NPM cannot find module 'date-fns/local/en-US' in react-date-range package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I've been using package `react-date-range` for some time now. After installing some other package, my app suddenly crashes with the following error message as I do `npm start`

[image: Error message from npm]

I have **NO** idea where this is coming from. Tried re-installing the packages after removing them, but it still complains about the missing `module`.

Here is my `package.json` file. (Don't mind the mixture of `material-ui` and `bootstrap` for the front-end)

Many thanks!

```js
{
  "name": "redux-easy-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.3.3",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress --display-error-details",
    "build:production": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --config webpack/dev.config.js --color --progress",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jestsetup.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "jestsetup.js"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/src/actions/**.{js,jsx}",
      "**/src/reducers/**.{js,jsx}",
      "**/src/constants/**.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/src/actions/account.js",
      "!**/src/actions/user.js",
      "!**/src/reducers/account.js",
      "!**/src/reducers/user.js",
      "!**/src/reducers/index.js",
      "!**/http_functions.js",
      "!**/misc.js"
    ]
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reactjs",
    "boilerplate",
    "redux",
    "hot",
    "reload",
    "hmr",
    "live",
    "edit",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "author": "https://github.com/anorudes, https://github.com/keske",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.3",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-less": "^3.3.8",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.0",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.6",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.4",
    "csswring": "^5.1.0",
    "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.2.1",
    "eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.1.2",
    "expect": "^1.13.4",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-open-in-editor": "^1.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "gapi": "0.0.3",
    "history": "^4.4.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "http-proxy": "^1.12.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "qs": "^6.1.0",
    "rc-datepicker": "^4.0.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-calendar-component": "^1.0.0",
    "react-date-picker": "^5.3.28",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.37.0",
    "react-document-meta": "^2.0.0-rc2",
    "react-forms": "^2.0.0-beta33",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-loading-order-with-animation": "^1.0.0",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^5.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.2.1",
    "redux-form": "^6.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "2.7.4",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "yargs": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
    "bootstrap-sass-loader": "^1.0.10",
    "clsx": "^1.0.4",
    "codemirror": "^5.33.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "emoji-dictionary": "^1.0.10",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "markdown-to-jsx": "^6.9.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.12",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "notistack": "^0.8.6",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.3",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker": "^2.0.4",
    "react-checkbox-tree": "^1.5.1",
    "react-date-range": "^1.0.0-beta",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-drag-and-drop": "^2.4.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.2.2",
    "react-notifications": "^1.4.3",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.13",
    "react-time-picker": "^3.5.2",
    "react-timezone": "^2.3.0",
    "recharts": "^1.4.2",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "uuid": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try deleting node_modules and package.lock and then install node_modules again

Comment: Yeah @MuhammadHaseeb, I deleted both and proceeded with a clean `npm install` but still not working.

Comment: Its hard to get an idea from that that snap, did you open the file and check the module path that error is referring to?

Comment: I succeeded in fixing the issue (even though I don't know why this is happening) by install the `date-fns@next` via `npm install date-fns@next`

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb I opened the file and check the module, but was 'adviced' by my IDE (PyCharm) not to edit the file.

Comment: hmm. I can assist you if you can share your skypeId.

Comment: Will love to, but will like to send that privately, how do I reach you?

Comment: on twitter @haseeb1009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. Just did `npm install date-fns@next` and everything was okay. Had to change some lines of code in app to match `date-fns` documentation though.